# Windows 10 AppInstaller hangs at 16%

Tags: xamarin, uwp, sideloading

I created a simple Xamarin Blank App targeting only the UWP platform. Then I created packages to deploy app in sideloading mode. Then the installation works well on my development machine but when I tried to install it on an other PC without Visual Studio, the AppInstaller hangs at 16%.

Note both my development machine and the second PC have the same Windows 10 version which is 1803 (17134.112).

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

Please note I use Visual Studio 2017 Community version 15.5.27130.2024

Comment: Have you got some error information? When you install it, you need to install the certificate at first.

Comment: Thanks for response. I installed the certificate before to try to install my Xamarin app. I have not any information about this error because the Windows 10 App Installer hangs/freezes at 16% without crash and without information message. I will try to create package for an UWP native app (without Xamarin). If it works, is it possible that Xamarin apps cannot been deployed in sideloading mode?

Comment: Okay, so it seems applications targeting the 16299 version of Windows 10 can't be installed in sideloading mode. May be it is a visual studio version limitation because it works if I create packages for an application targeting windows 10 14393. So I will update VS and retry to generate package targeting W10 16299